# Can't read previously written JSON data (Unterminated String error) in Java

Tags: java, json, io, twitter4j

I'm using the twitter4j package for an information retrieval class and have collected some tweets. However, for the next part of the assignment, I am to use Lucene to index on the tweets. In order to do this, my thought was to save the tweets as JSON Strings to a file and then reread them when needed. However, I'm running into an error.

When the file is written, I can see the entire JSON object just fine. The total object is quite large (2500 characters). However, when reading back from the file, I get a `Unterminated string at xxxx` error. I am using the TwitterObjectFactory methods to both write and read the string. Here is a sample code:

Writing:

```
        public void onStatus(Status status) {
            try{
                String jsonString = TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status);
                output.write(jsonString+"\n");
                numTweets++;
                if(numTweets > 10){
                    synchronized(lock){
                        lock.notify();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Reading:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);


    while(input.hasNext()){
        Status status = TwitterObjectFactory.createStatus(input.nextLine());
        System.out.println(status.getUser().getScreenName());
    }
```

This works only some of the time. If I run the program multiple times and get many tweets, the program almost always crashes after 2-3 tweets have been read from the file, always with the same error. If you'd like to replicate the code, you can follow [this example](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/stream/PrintSampleStream.java). I've added a synchronized block in order to close the stream after 10 tweets, but it's not necessary to replicate the error.

Can someone explain what is happening? My guess is that there's something wrong with the way I'm encoding the JSON into the file. I'm using `BufferedWriter` wrapping an `OutputStreamWriter` in order to output in UTF-8 format.

Edit: I do close the stream. Here's the bottom snippet of the code:

```
    twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    twitterStream.sample("en");

    try{
        synchronized(lock){
            lock.wait();
        }
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    twitterStream.clearListeners();
    twitterStream.cleanUp();
    twitterStream.shutdown();
    output.close();
```

Comment: Are you sure you are properly closing the file stream before reading?

Comment: @PavelHoral yes. They're two separate programs, and I only Reader after the Writer has terminated. The synchronized lock block I show allows me to close both the TwitterStream and the BufferedWriter object before the Writer program terminates.

Comment: Post the corrupted file. Watching your code (not familiar with Twitter4j) I sense race-condition when closing the output stream (closing it while the `onStatus` is still writing 11th tweet).

Comment: @PavelHoral the output is entirely valid, according to the link suggested in Aaron's answer. Here's the file in google drive:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B01epMbJL7uUdnA4SFNHM3l4MGc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the code where you properly close the `BufferedWriter`. If you don't close it manually before the first program ends, then data might remain in the internal buffer and never written to the file.

You can also try to open the file in a text editor and look at the contents. Tools like http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer or http://jsonlint.com/ allow you to validate/beautify the contents to see errors.

Lastly, try `BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8" ) )`. Maybe non-ASCII characters in the input are confusing `Scanner`.

Comment: I tried http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer and checked all of the tweets. It appears to be valid. Could there be a problem with how I am reading it? When the exception is thrown, I print the line, and it is indeed truncated at a random location, but when I look in the file itself, the line in fact continues.

Comment: @Teofrostus: Closing looks good. `Scanner` should read the whole line, no matter how long it is. Can you try to replace it with a `BufferedReader`? Also don't forget to read with `InputStreamReader`, so you can specify the input encoding.

Comment: Wow, that worked for some reason. Using a BufferedReader, suddenly there are no problems whatsoever. Do you have any idea why this could be the case?

Comment: I'm not sure; `Scanner` should work when the input contains Umlauts and other international characters, no matter if you supply the correct charset :-/

Comment: The updated question does not construct scanner with encoding parameter... so it uses default platform encoding, which might not be utf-8 (mostly in case of Windows).

Comment: @PavelHoral: True but most Windows code pages can parse UTF-8 data (even though it would look odd when printed, it doesn't throw exceptions or fail parsing) and UTF-8 can't ever produce `\n` as the part of the encoding process, so the lines really should be truncated. I simply don't see why any input data would return truncated lines with `Scanner` :-/

Comment: The issue might be backslash before quote character. Maybe there are other potential causes.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to flush your output, before you notify the reader. Otherwise parts of your String will stay in the buffer.

```
    public void onStatus(Status status) {
        try{
            String jsonString = TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status);
            output.write(jsonString+"\n");
            output.flush();
            numTweets++;
            if(numTweets > 10){
                synchronized(lock){
                    lock.notify();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. The synchronized block is used so that I can close the stream after receiving a certain number of tweets. Please see the edit above.